# i have got the error for w3af like "/usr/bin/w3af_console: 4: /usr/bin/python2.5: not found" is there any solution for that

Tags: python

I have installed w3af using command "sudo apt-get install w3af" but on firing command "w3af_console" it shows me error as shown under

/usr/bin/w3af_console: 4: /usr/bin/python2.5: not found

i have already installed python2.5.6 as shown in http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/w3af/wiki/HowToInstallPython2.5 but still getting the same problem

Please guide me in positive direction

Comment: Where is `python2.5` installed? If you built Python from source, it's most likely in `/usr/local/bin` and not `/usr/bin` as `w3af_console` expects.

Comment: You r right Joachim Pileborg, i dont have python2.5 at /usr/bin as w3af_console require, although it's present in /usr/local/bin. Can u guide me how can i put python2.5 in /usr/bin.......... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest installing `python2.5` with `apt-get` and not manually. Second, if `w3af` package wants `python2.5`, it should depend on it so I suggest filing a bug report for that package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it happens because Kali Linux ships by default with Python2.6/2.7 and not 2.5. 
I checked on mine, and it showed the same error.

Here is what you need to do.

```
nano /usr/bin/w3af_console
```

and change the **`/usr/bin/python2.5`** to **`/usr/bin/python2.6`**

That would definitely work out.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

If `python2.5` isn't in `/usr/bin` there are a couple of different solutions you can try.

The first is to change the path used to look for programs. This is done on of two files: `~/.profile` if you have it, otherwise `~/.bashrc` (or similar file depending on your shell.) In that file add the following line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

The other solution is to create a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` pointing to the program you want:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.5 /usr/bin
```

The first solution (changing `PATH`) is what I would recommend. But then you have to update the w3af_console program, to call `/usr/local/bin/python2.5` instead.

Comment: I have used last method i.e. the symbolic link bt after that i have got the

Comment: Changing `$PATH` won't work here as the program wants the absolute path for `/usr/bin/python2.5`. The symlink will work though this is not recommended. If `/usr/bin/w3af_console` was installed manually and not from the distro, I would recommend changing its shebang.

Comment: @wRAR Damn, forgot to add that. Edited answer to include that.

Comment: Note that 1) editing $PATH is not necessary here and 2) editing files in /usr installed from a package is bad and not recommended.

Comment: I have used last method i.e. the symbolic link bt after that i have got another error which i am mentioning here                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/share/w3af/w3af_console", line 96, in <module>
          errCode = main()
       File "/usr/share/w3af/core/controllers/intrusionTools/execMethodHelpers.py", line   25, in <module>
          from core.data.fuzzer.fuzzer import *
       File "/usr/share/w3af/core/data/fuzzer/fuzzer.py", line 43, in <module>
    import simplejson as json
    ImportError: No module named simplejson

Comment: You need to install `simplejson` module for python 2.5. As you've installed python manually, you need to install the module (and all other needed 3rd party modules) manually too.